# Нужно реализовать возведение числа в степень.Длинная арифметика

Tags: c, массивы

Пытаюсь реализовать возведение в степень длинного числа , который записан в массиве таким образом: заданное число записывается задом на перед , то есть В 1м элементе массива  хранится последняя цифра числа, во 2м - предпоследняя и т.д. до последней цифры. В 0м элементе  храню общее количество цифр в числе.

Ну раз возвожу в степень , то умножение самого на себя n-количество раз( сколько введт пользователь)

```
while (n >= 1) {
    cr = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= a[0]; j++) {
            cr = a[i] * a[j];
            k = i + j - 1;
            while (cr > 0) {
                cr = cr + b[k];
                b[k] = cr % 10;
                cr = cr / 10;
                if (k > b[0]) b[0] = k;
                k = k + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    n = n - 1;
```

Как исправить ?

Comment: Так, у Вас умножение двух чисел работает?

Comment: @Igor, да, работает

Comment: вызывайте функцию, которая перемножает два числа `n - 1` раз

Comment: @Igor, не понимаю , как это возможно сделать

Comment: Вообще-то замучаетесь возводить в длинную степень. Нужно реализовать деление пополам (именно пополам - не так и сложно), и возводить  в степень быстро - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Псевдокод.

Считаем, что у Вас есть функция `LongNumber Product(LongNumber, LongNumber)`, которая принимает два длинных числа, работает :) и возвращает новое длинное число.

Вы хотите возвести длинное число `а` в степень `n`:

```
LongNumber result = a;
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
  result = Product(result, a);
```

Comment: вообще не представляю,как это можно сделать , если  у меня не число, массив цифр

Comment: Под словом `LongNumber` и скрывается/понимается массив цифр.